# Help identifying this chainring

Tags: chainring

where can find online a chainring with fittings like this?

[image]

Comment: That looks very much like a riveted together rings and spider The individual rings cannot be removed of changed. Does not look worn, what's the reason for wanting to replace it?

Comment: The two missing splines look uncommon. Does the crank lack corresponding notches?

Comment: I want to change to 1X10. it came off Truvativ x-flow crank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the central spline pattern is proprietary to the X-Flow crank. Basically you will not be able to get a single aftermarket chainring to fit.

If you want to go 1x10, you cheapest option is to get a used 3x crank that fits your bottom bracket bearing, ditch the rings and install a narrow-wide ring in the middle position.

Comment: If the BB axle spline pattern is ISIS like I guess it is, I would personally advise to ditch the cranks **and** the BB too. The options will be much less limited.